# How to find the shortest path between Vertices, but have a limit to search depth, using Tinkerpop 3?

Tags: graph-databases, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I'm trying to find the shortest path between two Vertices (fromNode and toNode) in Tinkerpop 3, with the limitation that I need to stop searching after at some depth N.  Without this limitation I'll never finish as the graph is too large.

So far this the best I can come up with:

```
titanGraph.traversal().V(fromNode)
    .repeat(out().simplePath())
    .times(N)
    .emit(hasId(toNode)).path();
```

The problem that this has, and all other ways I've tried, is that the paths of length N are returned as results, even when they don't reach toNode.

I need to return all paths between fromNode and toNode of length N or under.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track

```
titanGraph.traversal().V(fromNode)
    .repeat(out().simplePath())
    .times(N)
    .emit(hasId(toNode)).hasId(toNode).path();
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I'd love to accept the answer but my version of tinkerpop gives a NPE for this.  I'll have to upgrade the Titan version I'm using to also upgrade tinkerpop. Will check back after that.

Comment: OK, I'm pretty sure I ran this against Titan 1.0 with TinkerPop 3.0.1. If you have a small example graph to reproduce the NPE, please add that to your question. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, this is working fine.  Thanks so much, my NPE was related to a combination of Times and Until.

Comment: A question though - how can I make sure that only the shortest path is found, and that the traversal doesn't continue once a path is found?  E.g. it doesn't traverse N links if it doesn't have to.

Comment: Got it, just needed to add 'limit(1)' on the end.